# Greenplum connector giving hostname resolution error in ibm Datas stage

Tags: greenplum, datastage

GreenPlum Connection error:

```
 Greenplum_Connector_1,0: The following SQL statement failed: INSERT INTO GPCC_ET_20200903233319813_84175_0 select * from table .
 The statement reported the following reason: [SQLCODE=HY000][Native=56,966,976] [IBM(DataDirect OEM)][ODBC Greenplum Wire Protocol driver][Greenplum]ERROR: could not translate host name "hostname_of_machine", port "8001" to address: Name or service not known (cdbutil.c:819)  
(seg5 192.168.111.240:6005 pid=38339) (cdbdisp.c:254)(File cdbdisp.c; Line 254; Routine cdbdisp_finishCommand; )
(CC_GPCommon::checkThreadStatusThrow, file CC_GPCommon.cpp, line 808)
```

Comment: Is that the actual error message? If so, "hostname_of_machine" needs to be updated to the real hostname.

Answer (score 0):

As Jon mentioned, "hostname_of_machine" needs to be updated to the real hostname